# como seleccionar datos entre un rango

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como puedo construir el SELECT, para seleccionar de una tabla los datos que están en el medio de una secuencia, necesito seleccionar de la columna código, los datos que en la secuencia estén entre el menor código, ósea 001, y el ultimo ósea 005, sabiendo que 005 pude aumentar con un nuevo registro.

BD

```
id | nombre | codigo |
---------------------
1  | Maria  | 005    |
---------------------
2  | Jose   | 004    |
---------------------
3  | Pedro  | 001    |
---------------------
4  | Marta  | 003    |
---------------------
5  | Juan   | 002    |
---------------------
```

PHP

```
$query_datos = "SELECT * FROM tabla1";
```

Comment: Puedes usar `BETWEEN`, por ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE codigo BETWEEN 1 AND 5` o puedes usar operadores de mayor que, menor que, por ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE codigo > 1 AND < 5`

Answer (score 0):

Replicando tu ejercicio, te propongo la siguiente solución

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE s(
    -> id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(100),
    -> codigo INT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.77 sec)


mysql> insert into s(name, codigo)
    -> values("maria", 005),
    -> ("jose", 004),
    -> ("pedro", 001),
    -> ("marta", 003),
    -> ("juan", 002);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM s;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | codigo |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | maria |    005 |
|  2 | jose  |    004 |
|  3 | pedro |    001 |
|  4 | marta |    003 |
|  5 | juan  |    002 |
+----+-------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, name, codigo FROM s WHERE codigo < 5 AND codigo > 1;
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | codigo |
+----+-------+--------+
|  2 | jose  |    004 |
|  4 | marta |    003 |
|  5 | juan  |    002 |
+----+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

> Donde uso los operadores de comparación `mayor que(>)` y `menor que(<)`
>   para establecer el rango de valores que deseas filtrar; además que
>   como en tu ejercicio necesitas filtrar por 2 valores, hago uso del
>   OPERADOR lógico `AND` que establece la necesidad de que ambas
>   condiciones sean ciertas; tanto la de la extrema ezquierda como así la
>   de la extrema derecha

Así también debe funcionar tu consulta

```
mysql> SELECT id, name, codigo FROM s WHERE codigo > 1 AND codigo < 5;
```

En PHP

```
$query_datos = "SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE $codigo > 1 AND $codigo < 5";
```

Te anexo los operadores lógicos y su sintáxis

```
Operador NOT y su equivalente es !

Operador AND y su equivalente &&

Operador OR y su equivalente ||
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```sql
SELECT
    id, name, codigo
FROM
    tabla1
WHERE
    codigo > (SELECT MIN(codigo) FROM tabla1)
AND codigo < (SELECT MAX(codigo) FROM tabla1);
```